# Jim Gatheral's ansatz

Tags: option-pricing, implied-volatility, stochastic-volatility, heston

In the Ansatz section of [Jim Gatheral's book Volatility Surface](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471792519) (page 32), he assumes $$\mathbb E[x_s|x_T]=x_T\frac{\hat w_s}{\hat w_T}$$
where $\hat w_t:=\int_0^t \hat v_s ds$ is the expected total variance to time $t$, $\hat v_s$ is the unconditional expectation of the instantaneous variance $v_s$ at time $s$, $x_s = \log(S_s/K)$, and $T$ the time of the European option expiry.

Does anyone have a reference to a somewhat rigorous justification for this ansatz?

---

As shown below in the comments, Quantuple found the answer by Peter Friz, Slade then provided a [newer version](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Dy2BGTNXJENa7a4Tc64pPKEveSJhD7xk/view).

Comment: Does this help: https://www.math.nyu.edu/~frizpete/finance/workwithjim/ansatz.pdf

Comment: @Quantuple: Yes, indeed. Thank you! The higher directory has a modified version and other gems as well.

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: @Hans did you happen to save any of the pdfs you found? The links are now dead

Comment: @Quantuple as well

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Dy2BGTNXJENa7a4Tc64pPKEveSJhD7xk link just to the ansatz.pdf file

Comment: @Slade: Thank you. How did you find it?