# What is the basis for the ansatz here?

Tags: volatility

I'm reposting this question:

[Jim Gatheral's ansatz](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/38123/jim-gatherals-ansatz)

I have the same question, but the answer given in the comment is no longer applicable since the link does not work.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SE. Please comment the original question and someone will repost a valid link. Thanks :)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Dy2BGTNXJENa7a4Tc64pPKEveSJhD7xk